# What loss function should I use to fit a distribution of points with a function with latent variables?

Tags: loss-functions, gradient-descent, fitting

For simplicity I am going start with a toy example.

Lets suppose we have a set of $n$ points $\vec{Y}$ in the 2d space, distributed with the shape of the letter `M`. These points are not ordered in the sense that the order of the points in the vector $Y$ is shuffled.
Objective: We want to get the coordinates of vertices of the 4 lines that best "fit" those points.

In order to to this I built a function $f$ that given 5 points $\vec{P}=[[p0_x, p0_y], ... [p4_x, p4_y]]$, it generates 4 lines concatenated with those points as vertex. I want to find the 5 points $\vec{P}$ that I can use to best describe the data.

So basically my though here is, given some auxiliary values $x$ in $[0,1]$ and my function $f(x, P)$ I can sample points from this function and compute the loss against $Y$, Loss(f(x,P), Y). For example if x is `linspace(0, 1, 100)` I am gong to draw 100 points from my function. I can draw `m` points. Whatever it works.

My objective is finding $\vec{P}$

If the points of the ground truth are ordered and kind of evenly distributed I can use the MSELoss with SGD and I can get the 5 points (I already tried this and it works with lots of different toy examples with complex shapes and more than 5 points).
I think I can solve this problem because its like thinking that we have an independent variable $x$ and we have pair of points $(x_i, Y_i)$, so $f(x_i, \vec{P})\sim Y_i$.

However if the Y points are unordered this loss is no longer working.
My question is then, which kind of loss function I can use here to find P? I am trying to find the best latent variables $\vec{P}$ so that the points sampled from $f(\vec{P})$ have a distribution similar to $Y_i$.

My problem is a little bit more general and I have a set of points $\vec{Y}$ that follow a line that curves through the 3d space so I would like to use m concatenated lines given by $f(\vec{P})$  whose distribution best matches $\vec{Y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the The Chamfer distance can work.
This distance is computed by summing the squared distances between nearest neighbor correspondences of two point clouds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).